# Php - Ajax Success no toma en cuenta true

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy intentando  enviar mi formulario y segun la respuesta de mi archivo php . Hacer algo en mi ajax.

(Use la funcion ) echo json_encode($data);

Pero, jamas entra en el true.

de esta forma es como  envio mi formulario.

```html
  $(document).on('ready',function(){

      $('#btsave').click(function(){
            
             if(validar()){  // si la validacion es correcta. Se envia el formulario

              var url = "registro.php";      

              $.ajax({                        
                 type: "POST",                 
                 url: url,                    
                 data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
                 dataType:"JSON",
                     success: function(data)            
                     {


                       if(data.message){

                            alert("Soy True");
                            // 

                       }else{

                           alert("Soy false");

                          //hacer segun 

                       }

                     }
                   });
              }
  
          });

     });
```

así esta mi archivo php. De esta forma  hago una consulta, Y de acuerdo a la respuesta. Quiero hacer algo.

```html
if($resultado->fetchColumn()>0){

   //echo "El correo  ".$correo." Ya se encuentra registrado. <a href='olvidepas.php'> ¿olvidaste tu contraseña?</a<";

     $data["message"]=false;

  }else{

    $query = "INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`correo`, `pass`) VALUES (:fname,:lname)";
     
       $pdoResult = $base->prepare($query);
       
       $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":fname"=>$correo,":lname"=>$pass));

       echo "Éxito";

   $data["message"]=true;  

  }

    

      echo json_encode($data);
```

** actua de forma Extraña, Ya que jamas entra en el true. Solo en el false, porque cuando envio un formulario. Y le doy enviar. a mi boton no me dice nada. y cuando le pongo de nuevo enviar. Ya me dice la alerta de false.(Y si dice false es que ya se encuentra registrado. ) **

Comment: Quita el **echo "Éxito";**.

Comment: Oh, es verdad . gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es que estás haciendo un `echo` a un `string`, lo cual rompería la condición que estás haciendo en tu `JS`.

Comment: Gracias, Es verdad!! <3

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tu problema esta en el primer echo, cuando lo haces la primera vez no llega al json_encode porque sale en exito, y cuando lo haces la segunda vez coje el valor false, y de ahi que entra en el false del success